# VBA field cannot be accessed even though the form is open

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am currently trying to get the data from the given field, but it is giving me a

> Run-time error 2465: Microsoft can't find the field 'Text103' referred
>   to in your expression

```
    Dim engrAnalysisForm As Access.Form
    Call DoCmd.OpenForm("frmEngAnalysis", , , , , acHidden)
    Set engrAnalysisForm = Forms.Item("frmEngAnalysis")

    Dim emissionPhase As String
    emissionPhase = ""
    If IsNull(engrAnalysisForm.Controls.Item("Text103").value) = False Then emissionPhase = engrAnalysisForm.Controls.Item("Text103").value
    workSheet.Cells(26, 11).value = emissionPhase
```

I have other fields I am accessing before that successfully as such:

```
    Dim specForm As Access.Form
    ' The form cannot be referenced if it is not open.
    Call DoCmd.OpenForm("frmSpcData", , , , , acHidden)
    Set specForm = Forms.Item("frmSpcData")
    Dim referenceNumber As String
    referenceNumber = specForm.Controls.Item("Text20").value
```

The latter code is just a bit above the former, and it's not just that control that I can't access, it's any control in `frmEngAnalysis` even though I am sure they exist 100%. I just cannot access any control in the given form for some odd reason, even though I can access other controls in other forms just fine above the non-working code...

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does `frmEngAnalysis` contain a subform?  If so, is `Text103` a member of the subform?

Comment: Make sure that the form `frmEngAnalysis` indeed contains a control named `Text103`.

Comment: Perhaps the form has a invalid record source or ill formed sql as a source, and thus the controls don't have valid values. And if the form is part of a navigation set, then that form is really a sub form, and again if no recodsource, then control values are not valid.

Comment: @Wolfgang Kais yes, It 100% does, it also contains other controls that I can't reference as well, so it's not just a case of Text103 but any control in the form

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal it is a sub-form, but other sub-forms are referenced above without any issues. I will have to check if the record source of Text103 is valid, but as said above, its not just Text103 that is not valid.

Comment: Controls on subforms can't be referenced this way. you have to know the name of the subform control, then you can reference the value of `Text103` on the subform like this (suppose that `NameOfSubformControl` is the name of the control that contains the subform): `engrAnalysisForm.Controls.Item("NameOfSubformControl").Form.Controls.Item("Text103").Value` or use a shorter syntax like `engrAnalysisForm!NameOfSubformControl.Form!Text103`.

Comment: That is somewhat confusing. You don't open the subform, since it is a child of a existing form, or some main form that you open. You can certainly open another copy of the form with openForm, but that will launch a whole seperate copy of the form that has no relation to some existing already open sub form. Remember, you can drop a sub form (same one) 5 times into a main form, and you will have 5 working copies of the sub form, and these forms are NOT part of the forms() collection. So, if this really is a sub form, then it is likely already open, and you would not need to open it again.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you state, the control `Text103` resides within a subform, you may need to traverse the hierarchy from parent form to sub form in order to access the control, e.g.:

```
Forms.Item("Parent Form").Controls.Item("Sub Form").Form.Controls("Text103").Value
```

This could also be written more succinctly as:

```
Forms![Parent Form]![Sub Form].Form.Text103
```

---

Alternatively, if you are unsure whether you are accessing the control from the appropriate container, you could use the following function to determine the set of controls that are available for the form you are using:

```
Function FormControls(frmObj As Form)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In frmObj.Controls
        Debug.Print ctl.Name
    Next ctl
End Function
```

You could call the above from the VBE Immediate Window (accessible using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> from within the VBE), and the names of all controls available for the form will be printed:

```
?FormControls(Forms.Item("frmEngAnalysis"))
```